# Component to emit event on mapGetters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I load my component, I then call the do something like the following:

```
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('messages/connect');
  this.$store.dispatch('messages/fetchAllMessages');
  // this.$emit('set-recipient', this.chats[0]);
},

computed: mapGetters('messages', {
  chats: 'getMessages'
}),
```

The commented section within created is the snippet that I would like to run but only on the creation of `this.chats` and not on any update there after.

If I try to emit the event where it currently is I get an error: `Cannot read property '0' of null`.

Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`fetchallMessages` calls your server to get the messages, right? that asynchonous process won'T be finshed when the meit is run like that.

If you make sure to return a Promise from that action which resolves after you have added `chats`, you can do this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('messages/fetchAllMessages')
  .then(() => {
    this.$emit('set-recipient', this.chats[0]);
  })
```

If you have trouble returning a Promise from that action, share its implementation and we'll fix it.

Comment: It's a socket unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to execute `this.$emit('set-recipient', this.chats[0]);` only after `chats` was initialized.

You have 2 options:

1. don't use `mapGetters` for the chats getter, just define the computed yourself:

   ```
   computed: {
       ...mapGetters('messages')
       chats(){
           const messages = this.$store.getters.getMessages;
           if (messages.length){
              this.$emit('set-recipient', this.chats[0]);
           }
           return messages;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Instead of doing it in the component, you can move the logic to the store and emit the event from there when you modify chats

Comment: As far as I can tell this method will emit everytime I update the stores state. Or am I wrong assuming that?

Comment: I also tried it like this (sorry about the formatting):


      chats: function () {
        var messages = this.$store.getters.getMessages;
        if (messages.length) {
           this.$emit('set-recipient', messages[0]);
        }

        return messages;
      }

And get an error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Comment: Yes it will fire every time it updates. On what line the error points?

Comment: I'm only looking to emit once. Ahh strange it doesn't like: ...mapGetters('messages').

Comment: If you only need to emit once then Linus's answer below is what you need

Comment: Even when using socket.io? I didn't think sockets were promise based.